# How to load existing http sessions from an existing server to another server?

Tags: java, session, servlets, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I would like to know if Servlet specifications provides a way to load http sessions into my web application.

The idea is simple : every time a new http client is connected, a new session is created... and I will send this session and its values into a database (for the time being this step is easy to do).

If this "master server" dies, another machine will take its IP address, so http clients will now send their requests to this new machine (lets call it "slave server").

Here I would like my slave server retrieve sessions from the old server... but I don't know which method from Servlet specifications can "add" session ! Is there a way to do it ?

PS: it's for an university project, so I cannot use already existing modules like Tomcat's mod_jk for this homemade load-balancer.

EDIT:

I think that a lot of people think I am crazy to not use already existing tools. It's an university project, and I have to make it with **my bare hands** in order to show to my professors the low level mecanisms that I have used. I already know it would be crazy to use what I am doing in production, when this project will be finished, it will be thrown in the trash.
For the moment, I didn't find a "standard way" to make it with the Servlet specifications, but I can maybe do it with [Manager](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Manager.html) and [Session](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Session.html) from Tomcat native classes... **How can I get the instances for those interfaces ?**

Comment: *Here I would like my slave server retrieve sessions from the old server* I assume you refer to the database rather than the *master server* since it has *died*. If this is the case, use a `HttpSessionListener`.

Comment: Yes I am refering to the database because the old master server would be already dead. I can use the HttpSessionListener in order to retrieve the session in the old master server and store it in the database, but the question is how to load this session to the new master server later. I have edited my original subject. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, you will need to validate if the user session is valid, probably by checking if there is an attribute that validates the user is logged in. At the time you do this validation, you can load the data from database into the user session. And I think it would be better to do this in a Servlet Filter rather than in `HttpSessionListener`.

Comment: I think to use ServletContextListener.contextInitialized in the 'new master server' in order to retrieve and load the sessions from the database, then my 'new master server' should already know if the http client is valid or not. I think I need to use Tomcat Manager.add(Session) method for adding sessions of the 'old master server'... do you know how I can get instances for Tomcat Manager and Session interfaces ?

Comment: `ServletContextListener` only executed twice per app: when deployed and when undeployed. That's not the right tool. And a Filter is more suited to do this job since it allows you to review the data per request. Still, if you want to do this on less times, use `HttpSessionListener` instead.

Comment: Also, if you start working directly with Tomcat specific classes then you're not using Servlet specification, rather your attempt will be implementation specific.

Comment: I would be very happy to use Servlet specification standard interfaces/classes for doing the replication, but I don't see the purpose with HttpSessionListener. How am I supposed to use HttpSessionListener in order to inject sessions from the "old master server" to the "new master server" 's memory ?

Comment: Well, attributes in `HttpSession` are basically a `Map<String, Object>` associated to an unique id per client. In [`HttpSessionListener#sessionCreated`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionCreated(javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent)), you can load the values related to the specific client.

Comment: In the sessionCreated method I have a HttpSessionEvent parameter which allows me to get the HttpSession generated by the "new master server", won't the JSESSIONID attributed from the "old master server" be replaced by the "new master server" ? Which element could I use to link the client with his old JSESSIONID & datas in the database when I am inside the sessionCreated method ? Do I have to use cookies for storing an "OLD_JSESSIONID" and compare it with the new one from the sessionCreated method ?

Comment: Don't use the same JSESSIONID since it's invalid and may expose your app to [session fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation). Instead, just start using the new fresh session object which data will be retrieved from database.

Comment: How could I retrieve data from database to the client's new HttpSession if I have not a clue about who he was before ? The client is not supposed to log in (sign in) a second time after the "old master server" and "the new master server" phase because this step must be transparent to him.

Comment: *How could I retrieve data from database to the client's new HttpSession if I have not a clue about who he was before?* That's one of the main points in session replication that's achieved by session clustering solutions, and I assume that's one of the main parts of your homework. You have to find a way to accomplish this. One example could be using observer pattern from your load balancer, and when observing that a node has fail or break, then pass the necessary data to the next server in cluster.

Comment: Session clustering solutions exist like here with Tomcat : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/cluster-howto.html and it use native "Manager" inside. JBoss also provide @Clustered specific EJB extension ( see here : https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Clustered+EJBs ). All those solutions are non-interoperable because Java EE standards does not provide solution when the thing is "managed-out-of-the-jvm" itself. That's for why I think to continue with studying "Manager" and "Session" native interfaces provided by Tomcat, because I don't see other solutions. Thanks

Comment: Ok then, the answer to your main question is "No, Servlet specification doesn't allow you to do that".

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly a new idea and is called session replication. There are a couple of ways to do this. The easiest ones imho are (in ascending order of preference):

1. [Jetty's Session clustering with a database](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/session-clustering-jdbc.html)
2. [Tomcat's Session clustering](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html). I personally prefer the BackupManager, which makes sure that a session lives on 2 servers in a cluster at any given point in time and forwards clients accordingly. This reduces the network traffic for session replication to a bare minimum.
3. Session replication with a distributed cache like hazelnuts or ehcache. There are plugins for both jetty and Tomcat to do this. Since most often a cache is used anyway, this is to be the best solution for me.  What I tend to do is to put 2 round robin balanced varnish servers in front of such a cluster, which serve the dual purpose role of load balancing the cluster and serving static content from in memory cache.

As for your university project, I'd turn in an embedded jetty with automatic session replication which connects to other servers via broadcast using hazelcast. Useful, not overcomplicated (iirc, you need to implement 2 relatively simple interfaces), yet powerful. Put a varnish in front of your test machines and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is supported by all major Java EE application server vendors out of the box, so you shouldn't implement anything by yourself. As Markus wrote it is referred as session replication or session persistence. You can take a look at WebSphere Liberty which is available for free for development. It supports it out of the box, without need to implement anything. You just need to:

- install Liberty [Download just the Liberty profile runtime](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments/)
- configure session replication [Configuring session persistence for the Liberty profile](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_admin_session_persistence.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-3-11-0-3-3-7&lang=en)
- install and configure IBM Http Server for load balancing [Configuring a web server plug-in for the Liberty profile](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_admin_webserver_plugin.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-3-11-0-3-3-6&lang=en)